# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un accordion de activo a inactivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Quiero cambiar el color de mi accordion cuando este activo e inactivo.

> Accordion 1: Activo : color : White | Inactivo : color : Blue
>
> Accordion 2: Activo : color : White | Inactivo : color : Blue

```css
/***
Bootstrap Line Tabs by @keenthemes
A component of Metronic Theme - #1 Selling Bootstrap 3 Admin Theme in Themeforest: http://j.mp/metronictheme
Licensed under MIT
***/

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Tabs panel */

.tabbable-panel {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Default mode */

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #737373;
  float: center;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a>i,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open .dropdown-menu,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a>i {
  color: #404040;
}

.tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.portlet .tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.color {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
}

.containerB {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E1E1;
  color: black;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.cuadro_intro_hover img {
  z-index: 4;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .blur {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style=" text-decoration: none">
          <h1> Bugs</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <p>
              <li>
                Se aplicaron correcciones en el formato de fecha de la pantalla... <a href="Ver mas.html" style="color:black"><u>(899820)</u></a>
              </li>
            </p>
            <li>
              <p>Se realizaron las siguientes modificaciones en la pantalla “SRVF015 – Consulta de inmuebles”... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(808891)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff;">
      <h4 class="panel-title">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style=" text-decoration: none; color: black;">
          <h1>Mejoras</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="Ver mas1.html" style="color:black"><u>(595367)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(726403)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>En el reporte “SRVR917 - Reporte de vida útil de medidores” el cual se genera desde la pantalla... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(789762)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo también con jQuery, primero que nada tiene especificar una regla css en este caso uso:

```
.inactivo {
  background: red !important;
}
```

y con jQuery hago lo siguiente:

```
$('.panel-title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('inactivo')
});
```

Lo que hago es detectar el `click` en la clase `panel-title` para después obtener el padre y aplicarle el estilo que he creado anteriormente, pero como este al ocultarse debe quitarse es por eso que he usado `.toggleClass()` para quitar y poner cada que se de `click` en un elemento.

Tu ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$('.panel-title').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('inactivo')
});
```

```css
.inactivo {
  background: red !important;
}


/***
Bootstrap Line Tabs by @keenthemes
A component of Metronic Theme - #1 Selling Bootstrap 3 Admin Theme in Themeforest: http://j.mp/metronictheme
Licensed under MIT
***/

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Tabs panel */

.tabbable-panel {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Default mode */

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #737373;
  float: center;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a>i,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open .dropdown-menu,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a>i {
  color: #404040;
}

.tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.portlet .tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.color {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
}

.containerB {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E1E1;
  color: black;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.cuadro_intro_hover img {
  z-index: 4;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .blur {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="text-decoration: none">
          <h1> Bugs</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <p>
              <li>
                Se aplicaron correcciones en el formato de fecha de la pantalla... <a href="Ver mas.html" style="color:black"><u>(899820)</u></a>
              </li>
            </p>
            <li>
              <p>Se realizaron las siguientes modificaciones en la pantalla “SRVF015 – Consulta de inmuebles”... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(808891)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff;">
      <h4 class="panel-title">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style=" text-decoration: none; color: black;">
          <h1>Mejoras</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="Ver mas1.html" style="color:black"><u>(595367)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(726403)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>En el reporte “SRVR917 - Reporte de vida útil de medidores” el cual se genera desde la pantalla... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(789762)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**
Por Petición de Shaz utilizando los eventos de bootstrap se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
//Detectando cuando se abre el collapse y eliminamos el fondo rojo
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  //evt.target es el elemento al que se le ha hecho click
  $(evt.target).prev().removeClass('inactivo')
})
//Detectando cuando se cierra el collapse se agrega el fondo rojo
$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  //evt.target es el elemento al que se le ha hecho click
  $(evt.target).prev().addClass('inactivo')
})
```

Ejemplo funcionando

```js
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  //evt.target es el elemento al que se le ha hecho click
  $(evt.target).prev().removeClass('inactivo')
})
$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(evt) {
  //evt.target es el elemento al que se le ha hecho click
  $(evt.target).prev().addClass('inactivo')
})
```

```css
.inactivo {
  background: red !important;
}


/***
Bootstrap Line Tabs by @keenthemes
A component of Metronic Theme - #1 Selling Bootstrap 3 Admin Theme in Themeforest: http://j.mp/metronictheme
Licensed under MIT
***/

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Tabs panel */

.tabbable-panel {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Default mode */

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #737373;
  float: center;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a>i,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open .dropdown-menu,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a>i {
  color: #404040;
}

.tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.portlet .tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.color {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
}

.containerB {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E1E1;
  color: black;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.cuadro_intro_hover img {
  z-index: 4;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .blur {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading inactivo" style="background-color: #fff">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style="text-decoration: none">
          <h1> Bugs</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <p>
              <li>
                Se aplicaron correcciones en el formato de fecha de la pantalla... <a href="Ver mas.html" style="color:black"><u>(899820)</u></a>
              </li>
            </p>
            <li>
              <p>Se realizaron las siguientes modificaciones en la pantalla “SRVF015 – Consulta de inmuebles”... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(808891)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading inactivo" style="background-color: #fff;">
      <h4 class="panel-title">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style=" text-decoration: none; color: black;">
          <h1>Mejoras</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="Ver mas1.html" style="color:black"><u>(595367)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(726403)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>En el reporte “SRVR917 - Reporte de vida útil de medidores” el cual se genera desde la pantalla... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(789762)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aunque esta solución es mejor que la otra en mi opinión, creo que sería mejor práctica utilizar los eventos de Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events , si lo puedes adaptar, tendrás +1 de mi parte.

Comment: @Shaz he adaptado a lo que me siguieres

Comment: @Shaz ¿Usar los eventos de [tag:bootstrap] para añadir una clase [tag:Css] que cambie de color al tab es más **práctico** y **Limpio** que una sola línea de [tag:CSS]? Muy interesante.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía si te fijas, el efecto es muy distinto. En esta solución se propone cambiar el color del fondo (y por ende el del texto también podría cambiarse), en la tuya únicamente se cambia el color del texto, lo cual se puede realizar solo por CSS. Si puedes cambiar el color del fondo con solo CSS, me comeré mis palabras y tendrás mi +1.

Comment: @Shaz Entiendo tu punto; en ese caso sería muy conveniente que el OP ponga si quiere cambiar el fondo o solo el color para que se le pueda dar una respuesta de acorde. Si quisiese cambiar otras cosas además del color, esta respuesta definitivamente es la más adecuada.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Una pequeña precisión, cuando dije más **limpia**, la estaba comparando con la primera respuesta que propuso JuankGlezz, la cual no utiliza los eventos de bootstrap, no con la tuya.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo colocando un color específico cuando el atributo `aria-expanded` es `true`:

```
.panel-heading h4 a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #3498db !important;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```css
/***
Bootstrap Line Tabs by @keenthemes
A component of Metronic Theme - #1 Selling Bootstrap 3 Admin Theme in Themeforest: http://j.mp/metronictheme
Licensed under MIT
***/

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Tabs panel */

.tabbable-panel {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Default mode */

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #737373;
  float: center;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a {
  border: 0;
  background: none !important;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open>a>i,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover>a>i {
  color: #a6a6a6;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.open .dropdown-menu,
.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f3565d;
  position: relative;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a {
  border: 0;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabbable-line>.nav-tabs>li.active>a>i {
  color: #404040;
}

.tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.portlet .tabbable-line>.tab-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/* Below tabs mode */

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.nav-tabs>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #fbcdcf;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>li.active {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #f3565d;
}

.tabbable-line.tabs-below>.tab-content {
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.color {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
}

.containerB {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E1E1;
  color: black;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-150px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.cuadro_intro_hover img {
  z-index: 4;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .blur {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.cuadro_intro_hover .caption-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.panel-heading h4 a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #3498db !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" style=" text-decoration: none">
          <h1> Bugs</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <p>
              <li>
                Se aplicaron correcciones en el formato de fecha de la pantalla... <a href="Ver mas.html" style="color:black"><u>(899820)</u></a>
              </li>
            </p>
            <li>
              <p>Se realizaron las siguientes modificaciones en la pantalla “SRVF015 – Consulta de inmuebles”... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(808891)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #fff;">
      <h4 class="panel-title">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" style=" text-decoration: none; color: black;">
          <h1>Mejoras</h1>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="cta-desc">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="Ver mas1.html" style="color:black"><u>(595367)</u></a>

              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Actualmente AMERIKA TI está realizando una depuración de los objetos que hacen parte de la versión del Producto, por lo tanto se envía... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(726403)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>En el reporte “SRVR917 - Reporte de vida útil de medidores” el cual se genera desde la pantalla... <a href="" style="color:black"><u>(789762)</u></a>
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```